# Postgresql Query Too Slow

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I use PostgreSQL to storage my DB, and I also create index to speed up the query time.

After I created index on table, the query runs very fast, about 1.5s per query.
But, a few days later, the query runs too low, about 20-28s per query.

I have tried to Drop index then Re-Create index again. The query runs fast again?

Could you help me resolve this issue or Do you have any ideal about this problem?

P/S: here is the query:

```
SELECT category,
       video_title AS title,
       event_count AS contentView,
       VOD_GROUPBY_ANDSORT.rank
FROM
  (SELECT VOD_SORTBY_VIEW.category,
          VOD_SORTBY_VIEW.video_title,
          VOD_SORTBY_VIEW.event_count,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY VOD_SORTBY_VIEW.category
                            ORDER BY VOD_SORTBY_VIEW.event_count DESC) AS RN,
          DENSE_RANK() OVER(
                            ORDER BY VOD_SORTBY_VIEW.category ASC) AS rank
   FROM
     (SELECT VOD.category AS category,
             VOD.video_title,
             SUM(INV.event_count) AS event_count
      FROM
        (SELECT content_hash.hash_value,
                VODCT.category,
                VODCT.video_title
         FROM
           (SELECT vod_content.content_id,
                   vod_content.category,
                   vod_content.video_title
            FROM vod_content
                WHERE vod_content.category IS NOT NULL) VODCT
         LEFT JOIN content_hash ON content_hash.content_value = VODCT.content_id) VOD
      LEFT JOIN inventory_stats INV ON INV.hash_value = VOD.hash_value
      WHERE TIME BETWEEN '2017-02-06 08:00:00'::TIMESTAMP AND '2017-03-06 08:00:00'::TIMESTAMP
      GROUP BY VOD.category,
               VOD.video_title ) VOD_SORTBY_VIEW ) VOD_GROUPBY_ANDSORT
WHERE RN <= 3
  AND event_count > 100
ORDER BY category
```

And here is the Analyze:

```
"QUERY PLAN"
"Subquery Scan on vod_groupby_andsort  (cost=368586.86..371458.16   rows=6381 width=63) (actual time=19638.213..19647.468 rows=177 loops=1)"
"  Filter: ((vod_groupby_andsort.rn <= 3) AND  (vod_groupby_andsort.event_count > 100))"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 10246"
"  ->  WindowAgg  (cost=368586.86..370596.77 rows=57426 width=71)  (actual time=19638.199..19646.856 rows=10423 loops=1)"
"        ->  WindowAgg  (cost=368586.86..369735.38 rows=57426 width=63) (actual time=19638.194..19642.030 rows=10423 loops=1)"
"              ->  Sort  (cost=368586.86..368730.43 rows=57426 width=55) (actual time=19638.185..19638.984 rows=10423 loops=1)"
"                    Sort Key: vod_sortby_view.category, vod_sortby_view.event_count DESC"
"                    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1679kB"
"                    ->  Subquery Scan on vod_sortby_view  (cost=350535.62..362084.01 rows=57426 width=55) (actual  time=16478.589..19629.400 rows=10423 loops=1)"
"                          ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=350535.62..361509.75 rows=57426 width=55) (actual time=16478.589..19628.381 rows=10423 loops=1)"
"                                Group Key: vod_content.category, vod_content.video_title"
"                                ->  Sort  (cost=350535.62..353135.58 rows=1039987 width=51) (actual time=16478.570..19436.741 rows=1275817 loops=1)"
"                                      Sort Key: vod_content.category, vod_content.video_title"
"                                      Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 76176kB"
"                                      ->  Hash Join  (cost=95179.29..175499.62 rows=1039987 width=51) (actual time=299.040..807.418 rows=1275817 loops=1)"
"                                            Hash Cond: (inv.hash_value = content_hash.hash_value)"
"                                            ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on inventory_stats inv  (cost=48708.84..114604.81 rows=1073198 width=23) (actual time=133.873..269.249 rows=1397466 loops=1)"
"                                                  Recheck Cond: ((""time"" >= '2017-02-06 08:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (""time"" <= '2017-03-06 08:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
"                                                  Heap Blocks: exact=11647"
"                                                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on inventory_stats_pkey  (cost=0.00..48440.54 rows=1073198 width=0) (actual time=132.113..132.113 rows=1397466 loops=1)"
"                                                        Index Cond: ((""time"" >= '2017-02-06 08:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (""time"" <= '2017-03-06 08:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
"                                            ->  Hash  (cost=46373.37..46373.37 rows=7766 width=66) (actual time=165.125..165.125 rows=13916 loops=1)"
"                                                  Buckets: 16384 (originally 8192)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 1505kB"
"                                                  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.72..46373.37 rows=7766 width=66) (actual time=0.045..159.441 rows=13916 loops=1)"
"                                                        ->  Seq Scan on content_hash  (cost=0.00..389.14 rows=8014 width=43) (actual time=0.007..2.185 rows=16365 loops=1)"
"                                                        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on vod_content  (cost=1.72..5.73 rows=1 width=72) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=16365)"
"                                                              Recheck Cond: (content_id = content_hash.content_value)"
"                                                              Filter: (category IS NOT NULL)"
"                                                              Rows Removed by Filter: 0"
"                                                              Heap Blocks: exact=15243"
"                                                              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on vod_content_pkey  (cost=0.00..1.72 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=16365)"
"                                                                    Index Cond: (content_id = content_hash.content_value)"
"Planning time: 1.665 ms"
"Execution time: 19655.693 ms"
```

Comment: I'm gonna say your real problem is having that many nested sub-selects. Maybe instead you should ask about improving that query.

Comment: Thank you for comment, but, why the query runs fast after i created index, then It's too slow?

Comment: What version of Postgres? How often are you vacuuming?

Comment: Hi Schwern! I use "PostgreSQL 9.6.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit"

Comment: I set default on all vacuuming setting. So, I don't know it runs vacuuming or not.

Comment: Would you add the index statement?

Comment: Also, I'm assuming `TIME` in the where clause is coming from the `inventory_stats` table. If so, then why the left joins? Since a TIME value is required any records from vod_content that didn't match are useless.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the the execution plan (when the query is slow) generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Thank you @systemjack I will update Select function from table ***inventory_stats***. But right now, the speed is fast. A few days later, It will slow down again :(

Comment: You want an explanation why query is slow and how to improve it, yet you keep us in dark and blind. Is it really so hard to post explain (analyze, verbose)  results on that query? Share approximate row count in tables involved and index statement too?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to `vacuum` and `analyze` your tables more aggressively, especially if you're doing a lot of deletes and updates.

When a row is deleted or updated, it isn't removed, it's just marked obsolete. `vacuum` cleans up these dead rows.

`analyze` updates the statistics about your data used by the query planner.

Normally these are run by the [autovacuum daemon](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html#AUTOVACUUM). It's possible this has been disabled, or its not running frequently enough.

See [this blog about Slow PostgreSQL Performance](https://lob.com/blog/supercharge-your-postgresql-performance/) and the [PostgreSQL docs about Routine Vacuuming](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html) for more details.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will check your document :). By the way, my table just insert and select. Rarely have delete or update.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt at a condensed version of the query. I'm not saying it's any faster. Also since I can't run it, there might be some issues.

Left joins where converted to inner since the time value from the second join is required.

Also, I'm curious what the purpose of the dense_rank function is. Looks like you are getting the top 3 titles for each category and then giving the ones in the same category all the same number based on alphanumeric sort? The category already gives them a unique common identifier.

```
SELECT category, video_title AS title, event_count AS contentView,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY v.category ASC) AS rank
FROM (
    SELECT c.category, c.video_title,
        SUM(i.event_count) AS event_count,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY category ORDER BY sum(i.event_count) DESC) AS rn
    FROM vod_content c
    JOIN content_hash h ON h.content_value = c.content_id
    JOIN inventory_stats i ON i.hash_value = v.hash_value
    where c.category is not null
        and i.time BETWEEN '2017-02-06 08:00:00'::TIMESTAMP AND '2017-03-06 08:00:00'::TIMESTAMP
    GROUP BY c.category, c.video_title
) v
where  rn <= 3 and event_count > 100
ORDER BY category
```

Comment: You can't use a window function in a `where` or `having` clause

Comment: Thank you @systemjack! But as @a_horse_with_no_name said, I cannot use a window function.

Comment: About the ```dense_rank``` function, I want to get top 3 of each category. Compare by number is faster than compare than Category name :)

Comment: New query should work...was able to test something structurally similar.

Comment: Thank @systemjack I have tried your method, but I think the problem is here: Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 76176kB". It is too long to execute this query.